# Methods in JS class - why the code throws error?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, prototype

Does anyone know why in the code example below JS throws an error when ES6 classes are just syntactical sugar on top of the constructor function and prototype pattern?

```js
// Example 1
class Cat {
  meow() {
    console.log('Meow meow!')
  }
}

let kitty = {};
Object.assign(kitty, Cat.prototype);
kitty.meow(); // TypeError: kitty.meow is not a function
```

Why then this code snippet works when it should be functionally the same as the one from above?

```js
class Cat {

}

Cat.prototype.meow = function() {console.log('Meow meow!')}

let kitty = {};
Object.assign(kitty, Cat.prototype);
kitty.meow(); // Meow meow!
```

Comment: Why don't you create kitty as `new Cat()`?

Comment: Or, if you must `let kitty = Object.create(Cat.prototype);`

Answer (score 6):

`Object.assign` copies the enumerable properties of one or more source objects to a target object. Unless defined so, methods are by default non-enumerable. `Object.create` on the other hand, can create a new instance of your class if, for some reason, you want to do it this way.

```js
class Cat {
  meow() { console.log('Meow meow!') }
}

let kitty = Object.create(Cat.prototype);
kitty.meow();
```

An example to illustrate how `Object.assign` works would be the following. In the example below, using `Object.assign` copies the enumerable properties of the two `Cat` instances to `kitten3`, which has a mix of their properties but is NOT itself a `Cat` instance.

```js
var id = 1;

class Cat {
  constructor(name) {
    this.id = id++;
    if (name) this.name = name;
  }
}

let kitty1 = new Cat("Lucy");
console.log(kitty1.id, kitty1.name, kitty1 instanceof Cat);

let kitty2 = new Cat();
console.log(kitty2.id, kitty2.name, kitty2 instanceof Cat);

let kitty3 = {};
Object.assign(kitty3, kitty1, kitty2);
console.log(kitty3.id, kitty3.name, kitty3 instanceof Cat);
```

In your updated code where you set `Cat.prototype.meow = function() {}`, you do so directly which makes it an enumerable property of the object (prototype), which is why `Object.assign` works. You can see the difference using `Object.keys`. A closer equivalent to the first declaration would be to define the method using `Object.defineProperty` and making it non-enumerable:

```js
class Cat1 {
  meow() { console.log('Meow meow!') }
}

class Cat2 {}
Cat2.prototype.meow = function() { console.log('Meow meow!') }

class Cat3 {}
Object.defineProperty(Cat3.prototype, "meow", {
  value: function() { console.log('Meow meow!') },
  enumerable: false
});

console.log("Cat1: ", Object.keys(Cat1.prototype));
console.log("Cat2: ", Object.keys(Cat2.prototype));
console.log("Cat3: ", Object.keys(Cat3.prototype));
```

Comment: I have edited the question as I am not sure why the second code snippet works when it should be functionally the same as the one from Example 1